# Unexpected/weird results using OLE clipboard and classic clipboard, or do I miss something?

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, clipboard, ole

I'm trying to do the following trick:

1. I have `IDataObject*` to be set into the clipboard, so I'm using `OleSetClipboard()` to set it into the clipboard.
2. I have another `CLIPFORMAT` I want to add to the clipboard, but I can't do it with `OleSetClipboard()` because the `IDataObject*` I receive does not implement `SetData()` method. So, to overcome this limitation I `OpenClipboard()` with `GetClipboardOwner()`, this way, I can `SetClipboardData()` to the clipboard without `EmptyClipboard()` first.

Now, it all works well, but what happens is that `OleGetClipboard()` does not return the data I placed in the clipboard using `SetClipboardData()`, but I can using `GetClipboardData()`.

I can imagine why this happens (It just returns the `IDataObject*`), so I tried to `OleFlushClipboard()` to delete the `IDataObject*`, and `OleGetClipboard()` again to let the OS rebuild a new `IDataObject*`, and **it still didn't contain** the `CLIPFORMAT` added by `SetClipboardData()`.

Does anyone have any idea how to overcome this issue? or a different trick? or even explain why it works this way? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just tried this (on Windows 7) and it appears to work but only cross-process:

- In a different process to the clipboard owner, OleGetClipboard returns a data object that contains all of the formats (i.e. the original formats from the data object and the extra ones added to the clipboard).
- In the same process, OleGetClipboard always returns a data object that does not contain the extra clipboard formats.

In both cases, calling OleFlushClipboard makes no difference.

Anyway, this doesn't seem like a terribly robust solution.  What you can do instead is create your own data object that responds to the formats it knows about and delegates other formats to the original data object.  The EnumFormatEtc method would combine formats from both objects, and so on.  [This article](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2008/03/11/8080077.aspx) has the skeleton of a simple data object you could extend.

Comment: Pretty good idea :-). I should've thought of that! Guess that sometimes you just need to take a step back...

But do you have an idea why it works this way? I couldn't find any extra-data that might hint the process of the types he used to hold before the flush.